# How to Setup R To Work Within Jupyter Notebook IDE

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, environment

I'm trying to be able to code in R within a Jupyter Notebook IDE.  I followed the instructions on this site very carefully: [website link](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/tutorials/r-lang/)

But after installation, I open jupyter notebook from newly created R environment in Anaconda navigator >> go to New in Notebook >> there is no option to select R.  Only Python 3.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Run these two commands in your terminal-

```
conda config --add channels r
conda install --yes r-irkernel
```

Comment: I gave the above a try but it did not work.  I still don't see R option when I click on "New" in Notebook

Comment: Did you add R to the path, though? If you don't add R to the path, it won't show on the list.

Comment: please be very specific ... what path are you referring to?

Comment: Refer to this article, https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/ . It applies to any programs, including R.

Comment: Downvoting because this is a lazy and irresponsible post. If you wish to make it unlazy, explain what the IRkernel package is and why it is needed. If you wish to make it responsible, avoid telling users to change global configuration settings without explanation (in fact, the channel command is useless, since `r` channel is a subset of `defaults`), don't promote bad habits (e.g., using the `--yes` flag when mutating an env interactively), and help users ensure the correct env is activated when suggesting a mutating command (either include `conda activate` or include `--name|-n` argument).